# Placing two divs next to each other, which should fill up the space, when both divs are of unknown width

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML markup:

```
 <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='left'> Text text text </div>
    <div class='right'>
         <button></button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Let's say that the button is of variable width (because of the text that appears on it). Is it possible in plain css, to place the `.left` and `.right` div next to each other, and the `.left` div should take up the space remaining after the width of the `button` element was calculated?

Comment: Consider using a table https://jsfiddle.net/hohL4c3f/

Comment: @NachoDawg A table-based layout solution is very two thousand and late. There is flexbox and CSS grid now.

Comment: @Terry something-something flexbox is not supported everywhere and he might not want a flex grid installed, or to hassle with implementing the css and mediaq uerries

Comment: @NachoDawg Not sure when is the last time you actually checked, but flexbox is supported in 97% of browsers today http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: touche, I learned something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`.

> `flex: <positive-number>`
>
> Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.Equivalent to flex:  1 0.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='left'> Text text text </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to solve it!:) Care to explain how this works? I will mark it as accepted anyways, just curious:)

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Updated answer, check once.

Answer (score 0):

Change the  `position:relative;`  of #right to  `position:absolute;top:0;right:0;` .

Alternatively you can put the right div before left div.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div id='right'> Text text text </div>
<div id='left'>
     <button></button>
</div>
</div>
```

The elements are drawn in order. The right is drawn before and the left is drawn around the right element which will position the elements accordingly.

flexbox is another good option indeed!